# What happens to a temporary stack allocated pointer when used as a return value?

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, singly-linked-list

I'm doing some basic leetcode questions. Here I'm trying to swap pairs of a singly-linked list using recursion. The code below passes the tests but some point eludes me. `new_head` is a pointer created on the stack. I understand it means that once the function returns it is cleaned up and can potentially point to garbage. Is it correct to assume that here it works "by accident" and is not correct way to do it or is my understanding wrong?

```
/**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * struct ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     struct ListNode *next;
     * };
     */
    
        struct ListNode* swapPairs(struct ListNode* head){
            
        if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
            return head;
        }    
            
            struct ListNode* new_head;
        
            new_head = head->next;       
            head->next = swapPairs(head->next->next);
            new_head->next = head;
          
            return new_head;
        
                        
        }
```

Another question related to the code above:

if I change the order of assignments I get a stack overflow but I can't wrap my head around the reason why

```
        new_head = head->next;
        new_head->next = head;       
        head->next = swapPairs(head->next->next);
```

Nothing that is touched in this line `new_head->next = head;` has an effect on what happens inside the recursion no (well it must have but I missing it)?

Comment: If you find yourself typing "Another question", please stop and consider creating a separate question. Otherwise you risk having your question flagged as off-topic for lacking focus on a single problem.

Comment: there is a leak in this particular piece of code. new_head = head->next; the variable new_head is not used elsewhere. white new_head->next got overwritten in new_head->next = head;

Comment: @milevyo: `new_head` is returned to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Question

Return `return new_head;` does not return the object `new_head` to the caller. It returns the current value of `new_head` to the caller. That is fine.

### Second Question

With:

```
new_head = head->next;       
head->next = swapPairs(head->next->next);
new_head->next = head;
```

at the time `swapPairs` is called, the value passed to it, `head->next->next`, is the address of some node beyond `head->next` in the list.

With:

```
new_head = head->next;
new_head->next = head;       
head->next = swapPairs(head->next->next);
```

at the time `swapPairs` is called, the value passed to it, `head->next->next`, is `head`, because `new_head->next = head;` just set `head->next->next` to `head`.

Comment: there is a leak in this particular piece of code. `new_head = head->next;` the variable `new_head ` is not used elsewhere. white `new_head->next` got overwritten in `new_head->next = head;`